# C++ MongoClient index optimization for mass data bulk inserts

Tags: c++, mongodb, indexing

I am developing an application which inserts data into MongoDB in high frequency (thousands of documents sub-second). As such, index and storage space optimization is key.

So, before inserting the first record (collection names are dynamic), I would like to do the following with the C++ driver:

- switch off the autoindex on _id (I have a subdoc as the _id field), no clue how to do it with the C++ driver
- ensure one special index, this works with `conn.ensureIndex(coll, mongo::fromjson("{'_id.o':1}"));`
- set the index to background (no clue how to do it with the C++ driver)
- set padding to zero (documents are never updated again) no clue how to do it with the C++ driver

My insert command is then `conn.insert(coll, vec);` which obviously works fine for any number of vector elements.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1 of 3 solved: `conn.ensureIndex(coll, mongo::fromjson("{'_id.o':1}"), false, "", true, true)` does the background index,

Comment: 1,5 of 3 solved? With padding it seems I have to run another thread over completed collections and compact them..., still the most important question open, how to ged rid of the autoindex on _id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you're removing the `_id` index and replacing it with another index, yet still setting the `_id` field.

1. Apparently, you can disable the `_id` for a collection if needed, by extending the method `createCollection` from the `DbClientWithCommands` ([documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html#a0805134572c12fdf8557dd090dd64e45)) class. Of course, you need to also make sure that an `_id` is not automatically inserted by the driver automatically (many drivers to this, so for some people, this will still be an issue).
2. The current driver method `ensureIndex` has a `background` parameter you can provide ([documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_with_commands.html#a3da4730931090da228874c2f03f180fd))
3. I'm not aware of any way to programmatically control the padding. It's automatically determined by MongoDB over time for a collection. If you aren't modifying documents, I'd expect it to near be near 1 (meaning there's no padding). Check the stats to be sure.

For creating a collection without an `_id` and using `autoIndexId`, you'd need to create a new function, as the built-in one currently does, you'd need to copy the code as mentioned above and do this:

```
bool MyClass::createCollection(const string &ns, long long size, 
                               bool capped, int max, bool disableAutoIndexId, BSONObj *info) {
    verify(!capped||size);
    BSONObj o;
    if ( info == 0 )    info = &o;
    BSONObjBuilder b;
    string db = nsToDatabase(ns);
    b.append("create", ns.c_str() + db.length() + 1);
    if ( size ) b.append("size", size);
    if ( capped ) b.append("capped", true);
    if ( max ) b.append("max", max);
    if ( disableAutoIndexId ) b.append("autoIndexId", false);
    return runCommand(db.c_str(), b.done(), *info);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On 1., you may correct your knowledge ;), it is possible for any collection if you specify {autoIndexId:false} in the createCollection call, the question is only, how does this work with the C++ createCollection() flavor... With 2. you are right, I found the parameter after looking into the parameter list :) 3. is still very important. Our tests have shown that MongoDB assigns between 1 and 3! times the storage size for collections before compacting them.

Comment: No, #1 still only applies to capped collections (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/). While #3 might be important, I don't believe there's a way to specify it. MongoDb determines it statistically at runtime. Why do you think it's critical? Overtime, it should drop to 1.

Comment: The correct answer is: According to the *currently available documentation* of MongoDB it might be read as it would only be  possible for capped collections. In reality, it IS possible for regular collections and I just found the way with the C++ driver:     BSONBUILDER cmd;
BSONOBJ retobj;
cmd.append("create", collname);
cmd.append("autoIndexId", false);
BOOL res = conn.runCommand(LIT_DB_NAME, cmd.obj(), retobj);

Comment: My defines above. "BSONBUILDER" is equivalent mongo::BSONObjBuilder and BSONOBJ equals mongo::BSONObj.

Comment: My colleague has just found that there are two contradictionary pieces of doc available. One says only for capped, http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/create/ says it not

Comment: And on the #3 topic: I create collections with 50,000+ docs each 1, 5, 10 minutes etc. If some of them just eat up two or three times the storage they really require, that's not a good thing if you have thousands of collections finally - and they are not supposed to be updated or extended in any fashion. I think background-compacting is an approach.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect the new knowledge you pointed to. I had tried the autoIndexId parameter and was fooled by the way the console worked, as it still insisted on inserting an `_id` by default.

Comment: Also -- maybe you shouldn't have thousands of collections? The extra disk I/O for background compacting may have been avoided by simply adding an indexed field to a larger collection and allowing the padding to naturally approach 1.

Comment: Just to finally clarify (all works fine now): WiredPrairie (thank you for supplying proper source code for the createCollection() replacement!) asked the question why removing the autoindex on _id. It is for memory consumption reasons. No index, no btree. I simply don't need this index, while my compound _id field still delivers uniqueness (It's an object ID from another collection plus the timestamp). Queries are never executed against this combination, but on the ObjectID only. Therefore I have an index solely on my _id.o field.

Comment: Great! I wouldn't mind if you voted up/accepted the answer. :)